# Dynamic Imports - NextJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, react-loadable

I have a simple function which loads a script:

```
const creditCardScript = (
  onReadyCB,
  onErrorCB,
) => {
  let script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = process.CREDIT_CARD_SCRIPT;
  document.head.appendChild(script);

  script.onload = function() {
    ...
  };
};

export default creditCardScript;
```

Before I migrated to NextJS, I was importing the script with: `import creditCardScript from "./creditCardScript"`.

Sine NextJS renders components server side in Node, care needs to be taken to ensure that any code with a reference to `window` (which is browser specific), doesn't get called until `componentDidMount`.

NextJS solves this issue by [providing dynamic imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/#3-with-no-ssr) (a wrapper around [react-loadable](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable)) which:

- only load the component when needed,
- provides an option to    only load the component on client side
  (`ssr: false`).

I went ahead and implemented dynamic imports:

```
const creditCardScript = dynamic(import("./creditCardScript"), { ssr: false });
```

In `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
  creditCardScript(
    this.onReadyCB,
    this.onErrorCB
  );
};
```

But I'm getting this:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function`

I've tried to convert the function to a class and use the constructor to pass in `args`, but my code now fails silently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Neal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561731/neal) mentioned in the comments, all I need to do is something like this in `componentDidMount`:

```
const { default: creditCardScript } = await import("./creditCardScript");
```

[Link to the official tutorial](https://nextjs.org/learn/excel/lazy-loading-modules/lazy-loading)

Comment: I am confused, why not just use a regular function?

Comment: And then call it during a client side only lifecycle hook. Dont use the dynamic function -- that is only for react components.

Answer (score 2):

Export default only work with `import from` statement, you can try

```
export creditCardScript;
```

And on import, u can use like this

```
const {creditCardScript} = dynamic(import("./creditCardScript"), { ssr: false });
```